# JSON Array Iteration in C# Newtonsoft

Tags: c#, arrays, json, json.net

How to iterate through pure JSON Array like the following, in C# Newtonsoft?

```
[
  78293270,
  847744,
  32816430
]
```

or,

```
["aa", "bb", "cc"]
```

All the existing answers that I found on SO are in KeyValuePair format, not this pure JSON Array format. Thx.

```
JArray array = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<JArray>(json);

foreach(JObject item in array)
{
    // now what?
}
```

Comment: @SMeaden, OK, OP updated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Parse the string using static `Parse` method of `JArray`. This method returns a JArray from a string that contains JSON. Please read it about [here](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/M_Newtonsoft_Json_Linq_JArray_Parse.htm).

```
var jArray = JArray.Parse(arrStr);
        
        foreach (var obj in jArray)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(obj); 
        }
```

A simple program for your inputs which you can run to validate at [dotnetfiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/).

```
using System;
using Newtonsoft.Json.Linq;
                    
public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
    var arrStr = "[78293270, 847744, 32816430]";
    var jArray = JArray.Parse(arrStr);
    
    foreach (var obj in jArray)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(obj); 
    }
    
    var aStr = "[\"aa\", \"bb\", \"cc\"]";
    var jArray1 = JArray.Parse(aStr);
    
    foreach (var obj in jArray1)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(obj); 
    }
    
}
}
```

The output of above code is

> 78293270
>
> 847744
>
> 32816430
>
> aa
>
> bb
>
> cc

[Dotnet Fiddle program](https://dotnetfiddle.net/wbB08n)

Comment: Thanks user1672994, what's the magic behind `Console.WriteLine(obj)`? I do need that result in string format, not output to console. I tried `string js = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(obj);` but got the error of "Unable to cast object of type 'Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.JValue' to type 'Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.JObject'"

Comment: If you need the value as string, then use the method as `var str = obj.Value<string>();` You don't need to serialize the JArray again.

Comment: I'm trying to write a library that may get array of int or string as input, that's why I'm trying to serialize it instead of using `Value<int>()` or `Value<string>()`. Thx.

Comment: Since, the library would expect the `Type` then make the library method as `Generic` so that caller will pass the appropriate type. And then in `Value` method you can pass the same `T`.

Comment: k. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean "how to get values from iterated `JObject`?

```
foreach(var item in array) // var is JToken, can be cast to JObject
{
    int number = item.Value<int>();
    Console.WriteLine(number);
}
```